# How to use capybara console with google chrome and firefox too?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara, rspec-rails

I would like to use `capybara-console` with google chrome and firefox too.
If I run my test with rspec, I use environment variable `JS_DRIVER=chrome` or firefox and it works good. I would like to use this semantics too when I start my `capybara-console`.
I tried a lot of settings, but my commands in console run only in firefox.
So I want to use this. `JS_DRIVER=chrome rake capypara:console` or `JS_DRIVER=firefox rake capypara:console`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a rake task named `capybara:prepare_console` that sets Capybara.default_driver (maybe Capybara.current_driver) based on ENV['JS_DRIVER']